# Merge replication Error at the subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I was working on a merge replication on SQL SERVER 2012. I have one central server with the publication and distribution configured on the same machine.I have another three machines with SQL SERVER 2012 as subscribers. The replication is working fine, however I run in to the following error on all the subscribers

***The schema script***

```
if exists (select * from syscolumns where name = N'TransporterID' and id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Transporter]')) if object_id(N'[dbo].[Transporter]') is not null exec('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transporter] DROP COLUMN TransporterID')' could not be propagated to the subscriber.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a failed schema change.  You can either reinitialize the subscriptions or skip the schema change.  If reinitialization is not an option, then you can skip the schema change like so.

You can locate the schema change you would like to skip in the table [sysmergeschemachange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188042.aspx).  Another way to locate the schema change is to execute [sp_enumeratependingschemachanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189521.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_enumeratependingschemachanges 
    @publication = 'MyPublicationName'
```

Get the schemaversion from the result set and then skip the schema change by executing [sp_markpendingschemachange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173801.aspx).  For example, if the schemaversion is 22:

```
EXEC sp_markpendingschemachange 
    @publication = 'MyPublicationName',
    @schemaversion = 22
    @status = 'skipped'
```

Comment: Thank you Brandon. Just executed      "EXEC sp_enumeratependingschemachanges 
    @publication = 'MyPublicationName" and the tables returns nothing. The table is empty. I remotely log in to the subscriber and see the same error.

Comment: Did you execute it on the publisher?

Comment: How about in sysmergeschemachange?  Examine the schematext column and compare it with your error message.  Do you see it?

Comment: What is the schemastatus?

Comment: Ok, now grab the schemaversion value and on the publisher, execute sp_markpendingschemachange, passing in the @@schemaversion and @@status of 'skipped' like the example I provided above.

Comment: Command(s) completed successfully. let me remotely log in to the subscribers and see the status. Tnx